# How to prove that no constant can bound the function f(x) = x

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-writing

I know this is a trivial question, but how would one mathematically demonstrate this using a proof?

Comment: For any constant C, f(C+1) = C+1 > C

Comment: I do not understand, this only works for particular case f(x) = 1

Comment: @IllegalImmigrant no it doesn't, reread what he said. The assumption is $C$ is the bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is too much fun to resist!

I'm assuming that the constant $\Gamma$ bounds $f(x) = x $ means $\vert f(x) \vert \le \Gamma$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$; thus we must have $\Gamma \ge 0$.  If such a hypothesis holds, then choosing $x_0 > \Gamma \ge 0$ we have

$x_0 = \vert x_0 \vert = \vert f(x_0) \vert \le \Gamma < x_0, \tag{1}$

which contradicts $x_0 = x_0$.  ***QED.***

***Note:***  If $\Gamma$ bounds $f(x)$ in the sense that $f(x) \le \Gamma$, then a similar argument is possible; likewise if $\Gamma \le f(x)$.  ***End of Note.***

Hope this helps!  Cheers,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Answer (score 1):

Let $M$ be an upper bound for $ f(x) $.

That means no $ f(n) > M $. But $f(M + 1) > M$, which is a contradiction.

Either show the same for the lower bound, or argue along the same terms.