# $2x+1 \in \mathbb{Z}_4[x]$ has no roots in any ring extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

> Show that $f(x)=2x+1 \in \mathbb{Z}_4[x]$ has no roots in any ring $A$ that contains $\mathbb{Z}_4$.

I don't know how to start here... If $\alpha$ is a root of $f$, then $2\alpha+1=0 \Rightarrow \alpha = (2^{-1})(-1)=-2^{-1}$. I know that $2$ has no inverse in $\mathbb{Z}_4$, but I can't see what to do with this information (I don't even know it it's useful in this case...).

It's an exercise of a list of exercises.

> The next item is to generalize the result for $\mathbb{Z}_n$, $n$ composite.

I believe that the generalization is that $mx+1$ has no rotos in any ring $A$ that contains $\mathbb{Z}_n$, where $m$ is a factor of $n$.

I'd be glad with a solution or a hint :)

Comment: Isn't $2^{-1} = -2 = 2$ in $\mathbb{Z}_4$ ?

Comment: I'm talking about the multiplicative inverse.. So there's no $a \in \mathbb{Z}_4$ such that $2*a=1$

Comment: You're right. My bad.

Comment: Hint: zero-divisors are not invertible (except in the trivial one-element ring).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

In the ring $\Bbb{Z}_4[x]$ (and also over any extension) we have
$$
(1+2x)(1-2x)=1-4x^2=1.
$$
If $\alpha$ is a zero of the l.h.s. then ...

---

For the generalization $1+mx$ with $n=mk$: If $1+m\alpha=0$, then $k+km\alpha=k\cdot0$.

Comment: Not sure how easily this will generalize to your next exercise, though :-(

Comment: I thought it would be easy to generalize when I understood a particular case.. hehe but I will think about it, and will try to use your answer somehow.. Thanks! :)

Comment: The generalization will likely need a different basic idea. The hint I just added may be simpler than my first suggestion. I am just fascinated by ad hoc tricks like this in $\Bbb{Z}_4$.

Comment: So quick haha thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This one, like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/925832/how-to-prove-that-no-constant-can-bound-the-function-fx-x), is also too cute to pass up!

Let $\Bbb Z_n \subset A$ in the sense that $\Bbb Z_n$ is a *sub-ring* of $A$, and suppose that $m \mid n$; we can then without loss of generality, by flipping a few signs if need be, assume that $1 < m < n$ and that there is an  $k$, $1 < k < n$, with $mk = n$ in $\Bbb Z$.  Note that I have excluded the case $m = 1$; $x + 1 = 0$ has a solution, $n - 1$, in $\Bbb Z_n \subset A$ and I usually take "factor" to mean "non-unit divisor" in any event.  Let us denote the $\Bbb Z_n$-residue class of any $j \in \Bbb Z$ by $j_n$.  Suppose then that $a \in A$ solves $m_nx + 1 = 0$, i.e. $m_na + 1 = 0$ or $m_na = -1_n$ in $A$; set $b = -a$ so that $m_nb = 1_n$ holds in $A$, and thus $k_nm_nb = k_n1_n = k_n$.  But $k_nm_n = n_n = 0$ in $\Bbb Z_n$, hence in $A$, whence $k_n = n_nb = 0$.  But this is impossible in $\Bbb Z_n$ since $1 < k < n$.  So $m_nx + 1$ has no zeroes in $A$.  ***QED.***

$\Bbb Z_n$ has non-trivial zero divisors; that's what makes this fly.

***Note Added Wednesday 10 Septermber 2014 11:14 PM PST:***

***What This Question Is Really About:***  Having answered the OP's question, I turned it and my answer over in my mind for several hours afterward.  I finally came to the following conclusion, which I'd like to share; hence, this note.

The fundamental issue this question addresses is, in my opinion, stated in the context of unital commutative rings:

***A.)  Let $R$ be a unital commutative ring; let $\mathscr Z$ be the set of zero divisors in $R$, and let $\mathscr U$ be the set of units.  Then***

$\mathscr Z \cap \mathscr U = \emptyset. \tag{1}$

We recall that

$I.) \; \;  m \in \mathscr Z \Leftrightarrow m \ne 0 \;\text{and} \; \exists t \ne 0, \; mt = 0; \tag{2}$

$II.) \; \; u \in \mathscr U \Leftrightarrow u \mid 1; \text{that is,} \; \exists v \in R \; \text{with} \; uv = 1. \tag{3}$

Then the assertion $\mathscr Z \cap \mathscr U = \emptyset$ may easily be proved as follows:  suppose $\exists y \in \mathscr Z \cap \mathscr U$.  Then $\exists z \ne 0$ with $yz = 0$, and there exists $w \in R$ with $yw = 1$; but then $ywz = z$ with $ywz = yzw = 0$; thus $z = 0$, a contradiction.  So there can be no $y \in \mathscr Z \cap \mathscr U$; $\mathscr Z \cap \mathscr U = \emptyset$.  ***QED.***

The significance of (A) for the present purposes lies in its consequence

***B.)  Let $m \in \mathscr Z$ and $u \in \mathscr U$.  Then the polynomial $p(x) = mx + u$ has no zeroes in $R$.***

For if $\alpha \in R$ satisifed $m \alpha + u = 0$, or $m \alpha = -u$, then choosing $v$ with $uv = 1$ yields $m \alpha (-v) = (-u)(-v) = 1$, so that $m \mid 1$ or $m \in \mathscr U$; impossible since by assumption $m \in \mathscr Z$.  ***QED.***

Now observe that (B) yields as an immediate extension

***C.)  $R$, etc., as in (B).  Suppose $R \subset T$ is a subring of $T$.  Then with $m$, $u$ as in (B), $p(x)$ has no zero in $T$.***

For a zero divisor in $R$ is a zero divisor in $T$, and a unit in $R$ is a unit in $T$, and (A) and (B) apply to $T$.

Taking $R$ to be $\Bbb Z_n$ and $T$ to be $A$ provides a nice example for the seeker, since $\Bbb Z_n$ is familiar to so many, and all the key concepts are illustrated, if not explicitly, then implicitly through increased familiarity.

OK, I'm done.

***End of Note.***

Hope this helps.  Cheers,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***